# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is now December 2013, we will soon be resetting our Community Promotion Ads for the new year of 2014.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- mapping and cartography resources
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

#### [Basic stats](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3460)

Answer (score 34):

[image: Free and OpenSource Geospatial Database]

Comment: When shown next to a question, the black border appears only on the top + left edges - looks ugly (firefox 25.0.1 / Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: This image is the incorrect size (should be 220 x 250, but instead is 240x240), which would probably account for @dwurf's issue.

Comment: I resized it to 220x250, borders are ok now

Answer (score 33):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Should this be changed to QGIS to conform with the preferred nomenclature?

Answer (score 33):

[image: GDAL - Geospatial Data Abstraction Library]

Answer (score 32):

[image: OpenStreetMap]

Comment: +1 but the font could need an improvement (?) it was suggested already in the old ads http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3279/9006

Comment: Font has been changed. Is it okay now?

Comment: @neogeomat Much better.

Comment: The size of this picture is incorrect now, so it becomes stretched vertically (or squashed horizontally) in the sidebar.

Comment: The OSM logo has changed, it is now : http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/File:Public-images-osm_logo.svg

Comment: I changed the logo to the new one, kept the text undearneath and it's now properly fitting @220x250

Answer (score 25):

[image: An Open-Source JavaScript Library for Mobile-Friendly Interactive Maps]

Comment: Thanks to [@LeafletJS](https://twitter.com/LeafletJS) for their official vector files.

Comment: Thanks for the votes everyone :) Lets promote simplicity in GIS!

Answer (score 18):

**OpenLayers: Free Maps for the Web**

[image: OpenLayers]

Comment: This image is the incorrect size (should be 220 x 250, but instead is 256 x 256).

Comment: This could use a caption.

Comment: Soon OpenLayers 3: http://ol3js.org/

Answer (score 15):

[image: MapServer Open Source web mapping]

Answer (score 15):

[image: The Open Source Geospatial Foundation]

Answer (score 14):

[image: @StackGIS]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: that answers one of my questions. http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/problem-with-adding-pictures  There seems to be a problem with pictures. Do you see the picture?

Comment: @Brad I see the image fine on my end. I'll see if I can grab someone to look at this.

Comment: Thanks @GraceNote. I threw another post on meta about it but discovered it was my firewall. I think something changed about imgur that made it hit block. fixed now though.

Comment: @Brad Ah, gotcha. Those can be tricky sometimes, heh.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Geographic Resources Analysis Support System (GRASS GIS)]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Geospatial database on the cloud]

Answer (score 9):

[image: OsmAnd]

Answer (score 8):

[image: geodjango - A world class geographic framework]

Comment: Thank you all for supporting me.

Answer (score 8):

[image: GeoServer is an open source server for sharing geospatial data.]

Comment: Image needs to be 220x250 pixels in size, in order to fit in the ad slot.

Comment: image size changed as per requirement.

Comment: Awesome, thanks~

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to add a text to the picture (e.g. see MapServer ad)? Then a visitor of the website can see what is promoted.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Fast Java Routing Engine]

Answer (score 5):

[image: gvSIG]

Comment: Any ideas for a more meaningful _tagline_? I think the current tagline ("gvSIG") does not highlight what gvSIG is (and the linked page does not have a straightforward introduction on it, either.)

Comment: Maybe this page: http://www.gvsig.org/plone/home/projects/gvsig-desktop but only describes the "Desktop" version

Comment: yes it's hard to place a tag line that gives credit to the project, I always like to say that gvSIG are a project of several software, a community and also an association as on this [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/xurxosanz/gvsig-proyecto-comunidad-asociacin-5667898) but I don't feel brave enough to put it on a tag line :-/

Answer (score 3):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 3):

[image: OTB - Orfeo Toolbox is not a black box]

Comment: Very unclear what this is -- even after i click on it.

Comment: see otb tag in GISSE - http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/orfeo-toolbox/info

Comment: Looks very useful, thanks. Maybe something like "library of image processing algorithms" should underline the (very strange) icon.

Comment: Image needs to be 220x250, it's got the 220 wide part but it's not tall enough.

Answer (score 2):

[image: GeoGit: A Tool for GeoSpatial Data Management]

Comment: very promising project. I hope the best for it!

Answer (score -2):

[image: Fulcrum Data Collection Platform for iPhone, iPad, and Android Devices]